# No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parametro formal requerido (Error CS7036) - C#

Tags: c#

estoy recién comenzando a aprender C# y estoy haciendo un ejercicio que pide lo siguiente:

*Se va a simular **un sorteo** entre un listado de personas.
Para ello, se va a crear una clase Persona que guarde la información de cada una de ellas, los datos a guardar son: Nombre, Apellidos, DNI (como identificador único) y Fecha de Nacimiento.
Crea a partir de esta información la estructura necesaria para guardar la información de cada persona y que inicialice dicha estructura con unos 10 usuarios por defecto.
Implementa una función que dada esta lista de personas devuelva una persona elegida al azar.*

Aunque no tengo muy claro si lo que estoy haciendo está bien, me ha dado el error que he puesto en el título de este post y el error está precisamente en esta línea:

```
Persona.participantes.Add(new Persona() { Nombre = pNombre, Apellidos = pApellidos, Dni = pDni, Fechanacimiento = pFechanacimiento });
```

Adjunto mi código de todas formas, gracias.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("El sorteo va a proceder. Por defecto, el número mínimo de participantes es de 10 personas.");

        //Bucle para crear hasta 10 personas

        for (int contador = 1; contador < 11;)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Persona número " + contador);

            Console.WriteLine("Nombre:");
            string pNombre = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Apellidos:");
            string pApellidos = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("DNI:");
            string pDni = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Fecha de nacimiento (DD-MM-YYYY):");
            string pFechanacimiento = Console.ReadLine();



            Persona.participantes.Add(new Persona() { Nombre = pNombre, Apellidos = pApellidos, Dni = pDni, Fechanacimiento = pFechanacimiento });
            contador++;
        }

        //Generar número aleatorio para obtener un ganador

        Random numeroaleatorio = new Random();
        int numeroaleatorioparseado = numeroaleatorio.Next(1, 10);

        Console.WriteLine("El ganador es: " + numeroaleatorioparseado + ", enhorabuena!!");

        Console.WriteLine($"Datos: {Persona.participantes[numeroaleatorioparseado]}");
    }
}
```

```
class Persona : Program
    {

        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Dni { get; set; }
        public string Fechanacimiento { get; set; }

        public Persona(string nombre, string apellidos, string dni, string fechanacimiento)
        {

            Nombre = nombre;
            Apellidos = apellidos;
            Dni = dni;
            Fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento;

        }

        public static List<Persona> participantes { get; set; } = new List<Persona>();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Había añadido un comentario pero creo que esto merece una respuesta ya que es una duda que le puede surgir a varios principiantes.

La excepción que te está lanzando es porque en la línea problemática estás llamando al constructor de la clase `Persona` que no recibe parámetros (`new Persona()..`),
pero si vemos la clase `Persona` vemos que no existe ningún constructor que no reciba parámetros. Solo existe uno con la siguiente firma:

```
public Persona(string nombre, string apellidos, string dni, string fechanacimiento)
```

Entonces, tienes dos opciones: puedes crear un constructor sin parámetros en tu clase:

```
public Persona()
{
}
```

o lo mas lógico dado que has definido un constructor precisamente para crear un objeto de esa clase, modificas la línea que te da error por:

```
Persona.participantes.Add(new Persona(pNombre, pApellidos, pDni, pFechanacimiento));
```

y asi utilizas el constructor que has definido.

La confusión con este tema es que muchas veces, en una clase no se define ningún constructor y sin embargo, se puede llamar al constructor sin parámetros. Pero esto es un "truco" de compilador de C#, que si encuentra una clase **sin ningún constructor definido**, genera uno por defecto sin parámetros. Esto se explica [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors):

> A menos que la clase sea static, las clases sin constructores tienen un constructor público sin parámetros por el compilador de C# con el fin de habilitar la creación de instancias de clase.